# Как осуществить такой update в базу SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Здравствуйте. Есть такая структура:

```
ainc    |id |price  |dost   |name   |field1 |field2 |field3
-----------------------------------------------------------
1       |78 |232    |1      |qwer   |jdfglh |value2 |rghtr
2       |26 |139    |0      |dfwq   |hutrh  |value2 |gr46g
3       |99 |656    |1      |efew   |rhier  |value2 |fgdfg
4       |85 |134    |1      |43fd   |ergui  |value2 |xzvfg
5       |59 |614    |0      |vcrw   |hjfue  |value2 |dgrhj
```

`ainc` - auto_increment
`id` - primary key

Наполняю базу таким запросом:

```
INSERT INTO db (id,price,dost,name,field1,field2,field3) 
    VALUES ('65','659', '1','qwery','dfsdd','rgers','zxcdf')
```

В связи с тем что, у таблицы есть PRIMARY KEY, записи с НЕ уникальным полем ID в БД не попадают: `Duplicate entry - Error`
Но можно ли обновить некоторые поля, если БД увидела дубль?

Идет запрос к БД, SQL видит что запрос содержит дубль - то есть ID уже есть в базе, и ОБНОВЛЯЕТ строку, например, по колонкам price и fild3 для дублирующей строки (ID).

Премного благодарен за помощь в решении задачи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно для этого есть такая конструкция

```
INSERT INTO table (val) values (val) on duplicate key update key = key_val
```

Comment: Спасибо! А как внедрить в этот запрос? INSERT INTO db (id,price,dost,name,field1,field2,field3) VALUES ('65','659', '1','qwery','dfsdd','rgers','zxcdf')

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужен не INSERT INTO, а REPLACE INTO:

```
REPLACE INTO db (id,price,dost,name,field1,field2,field3) 
    VALUES (65,659,1,'qwery','dfsdd','rgers','zxcdf')
```

Если записи нет - она добавится. Если есть - старая удалится, новая вставится.

> ID уже есть в базе, и ОБНОВЛЯЕТ строку, например, по колонкам price и fild3 для дублирующей строки (ID).

Если же при наличии дубля надо часть полей оставлять от "старой" записи - то да, только ODKU:

```
INSERT INTO db (id,price,dost,name,field1,field2,field3) 
    VALUES (65,659,1,'qwery','dfsdd','rgers','zxcdf')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE price=659, field3='zxcdf'
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но Ошибка экспорта данных в базу данных: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE price=349, dost=krakow: 14, warszawa_janki: 10, warszawa' at line 2

Comment: А кавычки вокруг строковых литералов кто ставить будет? причём в правильных местах...

Comment: Спасибо. Ответ как справка. Спустя 3 года снова пригодился :)